# R inner join based on partial matching between 2 string vectors

Tags: r, inner-join, partial-matches

I have 2 large dataframes respectively with the following columns:

`> colnames(uci_ce_inv) [1] "Ndg"         "CTP"         "CNT_ID"      "NOMINAL_EUR" "FXD_CCYPAIR" "ISIN"        "SICOVAM"     "TRN_ID"      "SOURCE"      "INCLUDED"    [11] "EXCLUDED"`

`> colnames(assess_data) [1] "GROUP_SOURCE"  "GROUP"         "MD_ISS_NAME"   "MD_ISS_RATING" "MD_GROUP"      "MD_SECTOR"     "MD_CCY"        "MD_COUNTRY"    [9] "MD_REGION"     "MD_SEC_TYPE"`

I'd like to perform an inner join based on the partial match between uci_ce_inv$TRN_ID and assess_data$GROUP.
First of all, in order to do that I define relevant vectors for matching as characters:

`uci_ce_inv$TRN_ID <- as.character(uci_ce_inv$TRN_ID) assess_data$GROUP <- as.character(assess_data$GROUP)`

I tried different ways to perform the matching but the resulting daframe is always empty:

method 1:
`uci_ce_inv <- uci_ce_inv %>% fuzzy_inner_join(assess_data, by = c("TRN_ID"="GROUP"), match_fun=stri_detect_fixed)`

method 2:
`uci_ce_inv <- uci_ce_inv %>% fuzzy_inner_join(assess_data, by = c("TRN_ID"="GROUP"), match_fun=str_detect)`

method 3:
`uci_ce_inv <- uci_ce_inv %>% regex_inner_join(assess_data, by = c("TRN_ID"="GROUP"))`

method 4:
`partial_join <- function(x, y, by_x, pattern_y) {
idx_x <- sapply(y[[pattern_y]], grep, x[[by_x]])
idx_y <- sapply(seq_along(idx_x), function(i) rep(i, length(idx_x[[i]])))

```
  df <- dplyr::bind_cols(x[unlist(idx_x), , drop = F],
                     y[unlist(idx_y), , drop = F])
  return(df)
```

}
a <- partial_join(uci_ce_inv,assess_data, by_x="TRN_ID",pattern_y="GROUP") `

What's going wrong with this codes?
Thanks in advance!

e.g.

`  uci_ce_inv$TRN_ID=123456789

```
assess_data$GROUP=ewitwr/kdk/123456789/gfhdhfd`
```

all columns of assess_data for matchig rows should be added in the related uci_ce_inv row

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are `data.table~ objects, you can use this :

```
result_dt <- uci_ce_inv[assess_data, on = .(TRN_ID = GROUP), nomatch = 0]
```

The `nomatch = 0` ensures the inner join, otherwise you get a left join on `assess_data`.

If your tables are data frames, this should work:

```
result_dt <- inner_join(uci_ce_inv, assess_data, by = c("TRN_ID" = "GROUP"))
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for your prompt feedback! Unfortunately the proposed code provides the same results (empty resulting df). Anyway if I select a TRN_ID string and I search it manually in the GROUP, I can find multiple rows matching. How could I support you to find the solution?

Comment: Hi, this is weird, what do `class(uci_ce_inv)` and `class(assess_data)` return ? Can you also show us what `glimpse(uci_ce_inv)` and `glimpse(assess_data)` look like ?

Comment: '> class(uci_ce_inv)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"'

Comment: > class(assess_data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: > glimpse(uci_ce_inv)
Rows: 106,264
Columns: 11
$ Ndg         <chr> "10002239"
$ CTP         <chr> "10002239 "
$ CNT_ID      <chr> "27552814"
$ NOMINAL_EUR <dbl> 703146.53
$ FXD_CCYPAIR <chr> NA
$ ISIN        <chr> NA
$ SICOVAM     <chr> NA
$ TRN_ID      <chr> "16921794"
$ SOURCE      <dbl> 3
$ INCLUDED    <dbl> 0
$ EXCLUDED    <dbl> 0

Comment: > glimpse(assess_data)
Rows: 543,735
Columns: 10
$ GROUP_SOURCE  <chr> "Mx3"
$ GROUP         <chr> "Bond/ES041390072B/SANTANA 0.18 22.06.31/20310623", 
$ MD_ISS_NAME   <chr> "Banco Falasar"
$ MD_ISS_RATING <chr> "Am"
$ MD_GROUP      <chr> "Banks"
$ MD_SECTOR     <chr> "Financial"
$ MD_CCY        <chr> NA
$ MD_COUNTRY    <chr> "Spain"
$ MD_REGION     <chr> "Europe"
$ MD_SEC_TYPE   <chr> "Cedulas"
>

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the delay! Here I attached some details you required. Let me know if they're useful. Thanks!